# Is there any way to fill area between points?

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

In networkx i draw 4 points, connect them with lines so i get square. But i can not find solution to fill this wireframe rectangle with some color. Do we have any tools or hint for filling areas in networkx?

Comment: Matplotlib can do all your need.

Comment: @swatchai yes, but with mathplotlib i have to draw all myself with no abstraction about nodes and edges in networkx. a lot of wheel reinventing stuff...
i want to draw actually graph structure and select some regions of graph with color filling

Comment: @Apollorider The "region of the graph" as defined by the interior of some edge cycle is dependent on the way the graph is drawn. You cannot define it from graph theory abstractions.

Comment: You can use the output of the layout algorithms of networkx, which gives you the positions of the nodes.

Comment: @Leporello, yes, you're right.

Comment: @Sparky05, can you explain some details, how could i do that? thank you!

Comment: @Apollorider For instance you could use [networkx.draw_networkx_edges()](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx_edges) which returns a [matplotlib.collections.LineCollection](https://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.LineCollection) object, whose `facecolors` you can then set. You need to have or acquire some familiarity with matplotlib, though...

Comment: @Leporello, wow, really.  thank you a lot.